# Mongodb parallel queries via nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to run a number of mongodb queries via node Async. But they are still taking time to run.. 
The database is indexed and completely optimised. 
Is there a way by which I can increase the query speed time via mongodb admin ...  or like increase its performance by allocating more memory to it.

The queries are running one by one when I see on the console. and some are taking too long ... resulting in no response..

```
2015-12-29T10:31:48.958-0800 I COMMAND  [conn63] command consumers.$cmd command: count { count: "consumer1s", query: { ZIP: 37089, $or: [ { ADULTS_F_18_24: "Y" }, { ADULTS_F_24_35: "Y" } ] } } planSummary: IXSCAN { ZIP: 1.0, GENDER: 1.0 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:1 reslen:44 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 4 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 4 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 2 }, acquireWaitCount: { R: 2 }, timeAcquiringMicros: { R: 54270 } } } 146ms

2015-12-29T10:31:54.925-0800 I COMMAND  [conn62] command consumers.$cmd command: count { count: "consumer1s", query: { ZIP: 37024, $or: [ { ADULTS_F_18_24: "Y" }, { ADULTS_F_24_35: "Y" } ] } } planSummary: IXSCAN { ZIP: 1.0, GENDER: 1.0 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:88 reslen:44 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 178 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 172 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 89 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 89 }, acquireWaitCount: { R: 83 }, timeAcquiringMicros: { R: 1654781 } } } 6114ms
```

Hi please see the logs to understand my question ... 2 queries following same plan .. have a large execution time difference ... Please tell me the reason and how to fix it

Following info must be handy.
I am working this application on a Macintosh System. OSX Yosemite 10.10.2 Processor 3.2Ghz Intel Core i5. Memory is 8GB 1600MHz DDR3. Any suggestions how I can allocate more virtual memory to the mongodb

Comment: You need to look at your logs and monitor resource usage during the queries. There is no silver bullit to improve query performance

Comment: indexes are there ...

Comment: It depends on your real environment . It's high concurrency or big data ? For example , if it's high concurrency , you'd better use `redis` or `memcached` or other solutions. While,I'm also looking for the mongodb optimising itself ...

Comment: What is `ADULTS_F_24_35`? Seems it should be a boolean type, and I'm not sure that it falls under the GENDER index, but I could be wrong. Could you provide the document structure and the indexes you're using?

Comment: It also just seems to be really oddly structured. You seem to cram a lot of context into a single field maybe have field for: age/age range, or make it a boolean and then have an entirely different field for gender.

Comment: which engine you are using for MongoDB, also any random query hangs for long or it's certain query? what I mean the one which took less might take more if being called next time or it would always be on lesser side?

Answer (score 1):

As @Martin said, you need to profile. Use something like [cursor.explain](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/cursor.explain/#cursor.explain) to make sure the query is using indexes and to find weak points. Use whatever resource monitor your system has (like top/htop on linux) to see if it's running out of memory or if it's CPU-bound.

"The queries are running one by one" -- I assume you're not using `async.series` or similar, which is sequential.

Comment: Queries are never CPU bound, and I mean never. Aggregations, and huge inserts are usually the only thing that are CPU intensive. I've done a lot of performance profiling of queries, and queries do next to nothing to the CPU unless there is a huge quantity of them. There is basically no operator for regular queries that is very complicated, except for geospatial and text-search. Really only aggregations are going to consume much CPU, and still usually on the lower end.

Comment: Running in a series or parallel shouldn't make a noticable difference, anything beyond 200ms for a query is concerning for a basic query. The amount of time saved by running in parallel would be pretty difficult for a human to discern. Given its probably better in production, assuming you're not running 50 queries in parallel, that could become a point for DoS in that case. I usually run in series when I'm processing an array of an unknown size, otherwise parallel if I know the size won't be beyond a certain amount. They both serve a purpose.

Comment: All good points @tsturzl. The edited question has more useful info -- a high numYields and high timeAcquiring seem like they might be slow disk, swapping/paging and/or concurrency issues?

Comment: Look at the quoted output, I don't think the `GENDER` index is acting like it should due to the strange datastructure.

Comment: Oh right, missed that, good point. (I'd post that as a possible answer :))